# Mvc 4 is missing.and so is the Mvc 4 registry key after Visual Studio 2013 repair from its CD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Visual Studio 2013 will show the solution, but I see "Incompatible" under my project name with a blue icon in it.
 Hovering over this project shows a popup saying "This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio".

Here is what I think happened. I was trying to work with a project in c++, but it would not compile, after looking around the forums i decided that perhaps i should do a Visual Studio 2013 repair. 
 A few days later, I could not load my other Mvc 4 C# project in Visual Studio, and program and features no longer show anything about Mvc 4 (only Mvc 2 and 3 and 4 runtime). 
 I am using windows 10, and i am looking for the best way to get my Mvc 4 back (without a full uninstall/reinstall of vs 2013). I dont think i can use the vs 2010 sp1 Mvc 4 download because i dont have vs 2010 on my machine (but I do have vs2012). I tried manually entering the registry key entry ({E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}) and its sub key, it still wont open my mvc 4 project.
 However, if i remove this registry key from my .csproj, then it seems to work, however, i have many months worth of backups and i really dont want to change each and every .csproj.

The forums have many different solutions, but i have a feeling there is something i can do before i reinstall vs 2013 (I tried several suggestions). I even tried going back to my restore point, but it dosnt seem like its restore point was before the programs/feature repair from disk.

thanks for any help

Comment: user the web platform installer

Comment: Thanks Hadi, will take a look at it now. 
Any other ideas from anyone?

Comment: Hi Hadi, after looking at the web platform installer.I am not quite sure which to install to add my Mvc 4 back?” I wonder if i could download “visual studio 2010 SP1 – THEN, dowwnload the Mvc 4 for 2010 SP1?
 I also have visual studio 2010 shell (integrated) already installed.

Comment: check this https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Comment: Well that added Mvc 4 to the control panel, but it did not add the registry key {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}.to the registry.